# Lowercase table name on HANA with sqoop

Tags: sqoop, hana

We are trying to import one SAP HANA table via sqoop and the table name is in lowercase.
We are passing the tablename in lower case however HANA converting into uppercase and showing table not found

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sap://hostname:port/?currentschema=test" --driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver --username test --password test -table "lower_case" --target-dir=/tmp/aa1 -m 1
```

the error we are getting

```
[259]: invalid table name:  Could not find table/view LOWER_CASE in schema test: line 1 col 17 (at pos 16)
```

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

Please put schema name and table name in **uppercase** to avoid this error and for convenience use driver as well using parameter `-–driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver`

More details on:

https://blogs.sap.com/2015/08/14/importing-hana-tables-from-an-external-system-into-hdfs-using-apache-sqoop/

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

If the table is actually in lower case in the system, then you need to hand over the name to HANA in quotation marks.
In your example command line you already tried that but the shell most probably will remove the quotation marks when handing the parameter values to the program.
To avoid that, try escaping the quotation marks in the command line parameters.